# Locate a known directory within a partially known directory structure

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following directory structure:

```
D:\f0\f1\f2\<directory name>\bin
```

I do not know the `<directory name>` portion as it is variable, but I need to run scripts in the `bin` directory.

Comment: `for /D %D in ("D:\f0\f1\f2\*") do @echo/%~D\bin` should return the directory you are interested in (or directories if there are more); double the `%`-signs in a batch file...

Answer (score 0):

use a `for /f` loop to catch the output of a command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad "D:\f0\f1\f2\bin"') do set "folder=%%a"
cd /d "%folder%"
```

(Note: if there are more than one folder `bin` within the tree, this will give you the last finding only)

`dir /s /b /ad "D:\f0\f1\f2\bin`" will recursively (`/s`) list all folders  (`/ad`) named `bin` below `D:\f0\f1\f2` in **b**are format (`/b`)

Comment: To make it safer, add `cd /d D:\f0\f1\f2\f3\f4` at the top.

Comment: @double-beep Huh? The question is how to obtain an unknown path to a known folder (`f4`). How should we be able to `cd` to the known folder before finding it? Maybe it makes sense to `cd` to `D:\f0\f1\f2`, but `f3` is unknown. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, we can go till `f2`! :)

Answer (score 0):

With a friend I found the correct query

```
d:
cd f0\f1\
for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s "bin"') do @pushd "%~dpG"
d:\f0\f1\f2\14.23.11\>
cd bin
d:\f0\f1\f2\14.23.11\bin>
```

if it is to be a batch, then we add%

```
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /s "bin"') do @pushd "%%~dpG"
```